# unable to import BeautifulSoup (python 3.6 and bs4-4.1.0)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have installed `bs4` on my system successfully (using python setup.py install).
Now the problem is while importing `BeautifulSoup` in python I'm getting below errors:

```
C:\Users\dipankar>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\dipankar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
from .builder import builder_registry
File "C:\Users\dipankar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
 from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\dipankar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
>>>
```

Comment: Try updating your beautifulsoup package

Comment: yes, we were right. beautiful :)

Comment: glad it helped you. you can vote my comment then

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of google searches

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

As you can read [here](http://thefourtheye.in/2015/02/15/python-35-and-django-17s-htmlparseerror/)

> because HTMLParseError is deprecated from Python 3.3 onwards and
>   removed in Python 3.5.

I will recommend you to use other parser. Check [BeautifulSoup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)